# Could posix-threads created in one process run parallel across two physical processors?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, posix

Could posix threads created in one program (process) run on two physical processors?

I have some multi-thread code, need to run them on a dual eight-core AMD server node ( eight real core no hyperthreading). Not sure if these threads can be mapped across the two physical processors.

Also, it would be very helpful, if someone can suggest some linux command for monitoring CPU usage.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default commands that come with any linux distro 
1) top
2) ps

top - is interactive and displays different parameters updating them over the time
ps will be usefull with aux argument

```
ps aux
```

It will display different parameters about the active programs.

You can look man pages for this commands to make them display info you need

Comment: I will till I get 15 reputation

Comment: ps can show individual threads and process hierarchy if invoked like 'ps -efHL'.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the threads may run on different CPUs unless you do something on the OS layer to bind them to a spcific CPU.

`top` is one of the commands to monitor CPU usage

Comment: I will +1 when I get 15 reputation